Merging two sets of three to clear a joker in Rummikub
In Rummikub, can I merge these two sets of three together to clear the joker?
On the table:
Red 9, Red 10, Joker, and
Red 11, Red 12, Red 13


Yes you can.
This will result in a valid meld of 9,10,11,12,13 and a cleared joker to be played to a different meld.
Rummikub rules describe 4 ways to clear a joker, your situation is the 4th.


Actually it depends on the rules. The rummikub rules section regarding how to take jokers are different in post-2017 version of the game. The pre-2017 version is much less permissive than the more recent one.
